# Grouping DataFrame by start of decade using pandas Grouper

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of daily observations from 01-01-1973 to 12-31-2014.

Have been using Pandas Grouper and everything has worked fine for each frequency until now: I want to group them by decade 70s, 80s, 90s, etc.

I tried to do it as

```
import pandas as pd
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = '10Y')).mean()
```

However, this groups them in 73-83, 83-93, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a little arithmetic on the year to floor it to the nearest decade:

```
df.groupby(df.index.year // 10 * 10).mean()
```

Comment: That's a smart way to do it!

Comment: @sacul Thanks for the uv, returned :)

Comment: My chosen way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! I used this.

Answer (score 11):

`pd.cut` also works to specify a regular frequency with a specified start year.

```
import pandas as pd
df
                 date  val
0 1970-01-01 00:01:18    1
1 1979-12-31 18:01:01   12
2 1980-01-01 00:00:00    2
3 1989-01-01 00:00:00    3
4 2014-05-06 00:00:00    4

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.date, pd.date_range('1970', '2020', freq='10YS'), right=False)).mean()
#                          val
#date                         
#[1970-01-01, 1980-01-01)  6.5
#[1980-01-01, 1990-01-01)  2.5
#[1990-01-01, 2000-01-01)  NaN
#[2000-01-01, 2010-01-01)  NaN
#[2010-01-01, 2020-01-01)  4.0
```

Answer (score 5):

@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's method is cleaner then this, but keeping your `pd.Grouper` method, one way to do this is to merge your data with a new date range that starts at the beginning of a decade and ends at the end of a decade, then use your `Grouper` on that. For example, given an initial `df`:

```
        date      data
0     1973-01-01 -1.097895
1     1973-01-02  0.834253
2     1973-01-03  0.134698
3     1973-01-04 -1.211177
4     1973-01-05  0.366136
...
15335 2014-12-27 -0.566134
15336 2014-12-28 -1.100476
15337 2014-12-29  0.115735
15338 2014-12-30  1.635638
15339 2014-12-31  1.930645
```

Merge that with a `date_range` dataframe ranging from 1980 to 2020:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='01-01-1970', end='12-31-2019', freq='D')})

df = new_df.merge(df, on ='date', how='left')
```

And use your `Grouper`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq = '10AS')).mean()
```

Which gives you:

```
                data
date                
1970-01-01 -0.005455
1980-01-01  0.028066
1990-01-01  0.011122
2000-01-01  0.011213
2010-01-01  0.029592
```

The same, but in one go, could look like this:

```
(df.merge(pd.DataFrame(
    {'date':pd.date_range(start='01-01-1970',
                          end='12-31-2019',
                          freq='D')}),
          how='right')
 .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq = '10AS'))
 .mean())
```

Comment: Thanks, but you're right: @COLDSPEED method is cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
df.groupby(df.index.astype(str).str[:2]+'0').mean()
```

Comment: Be careful handling dates across multiple centuries with this... (eg; 1915 and 2018 will be grouped together.)