# Pandas resample offset from the most recent year end date?

Tags: python, pandas

Can somone explain what is going on with my resampling?

For example,

```
   In [53]: daily_3mo_treasury.resample('5Y').mean()
    Out[53]:
    1993-12-31    2.997120
    1998-12-31    4.917730
    2003-12-31    3.297176
    2008-12-31    2.997204
    2013-12-31    0.097330
    2018-12-31    0.534476
```

Where the last date in my time series is `2018-08-23    2.04`

I really want my resample from the most recent year-end instead, so for example from `2017-12-31` to `2012-12-31` and so on.

I tried,

```
end = daily_3mo_treasury.index.searchsorted(date(2017,12,31))
daily_3mo_treasury.iloc[:end].resample('5Y').mean()

In [66]: daily_3mo_treasury.iloc[:end].resample('5Y').mean()
Out[66]:
1993-12-31    2.997120
1998-12-31    4.917730
2003-12-31    3.297176
2008-12-31    2.997204
2013-12-31    0.097330
2018-12-31    0.333467
dtype: float64
```

Where the last value in `daily_3mo_treasury.iloc[:end]` is  `2017-12-29    1.37`

How come my second 5 year resample is not ending `2017-12-31`?

Edit: My index is sorted.

Comment: Okay, so if year 2018 is complete, then you want to basically ignore thoes date and just use up to 2017-12-31?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Grouper - Decades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145982/pandas-grouper-decades)

Comment: `convention='end'`? Looking at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Comment: When you `resample`, the bins are based on the first date in your index. In both cases, that seems to be `1993-12-31` so dropping the end dates won't affect that, which is why you see the same date ranges regardless of the slice.

Comment: I'd suggest either using `pd.date_range` to specify bins for `pd.cut` to group, or just adopt coldspeed's answer using integer division to group. every 5 years. In this case you'd want something like `groupby( (df.index.year + 2)//5 * 5 + 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @ALollz - When you resample, the bins are based on the first date in your index.

```
sistart = daily_3mo_treasury.index.searchsorted(date(1992,12,31))
siend = daily_3mo_treasury.index.searchsorted(date(2017,12,31))

In [95]: daily_3mo_treasury.iloc[sistart:siend].resample('5Y').mean()
Out[95]:
1992-12-31    3.080000
1997-12-31    4.562246
2002-12-31    4.050696
2007-12-31    2.925971
2012-12-31    0.360775
2017-12-31    0.278233
dtype: float64
```