# Python - I want to group_by 10 years interval and merge it back

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

My data look like this:

```
Pkey    CalenderYear
1   1996
2   2005
3   2010
4   2019
5   1985
```

and I would like to categorize it by decade interval with

```
decade = 10 * (df_CNratio['CalenderYear'] // 10)
decade = decade.astype(str) + 's'
decade.name = 'decade'

My desired outcome:

Pkey  CalenderYear Interval
1      1996         1990
2      2005         2000
3      2010         2010
4      2019         2010
5      1985         1980
```

How to do it in pandas?

Comment: If you do need to later perform a `groupby` have a look at [Grouping DataFrame by start of decade using pandas Grouper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50145982/grouping-dataframe-by-start-of-decade-using-pandas-grouper)

Answer (score 2):

Only need assign your solution to new column:

```
df['Interval'] = (10 * (df['CalenderYear'] // 10)).astype(str) + 's'
print (df)
   Pkey  CalenderYear Interval
0     1          1996    1990s
1     2          2005    2000s
2     3          2010    2010s
3     4          2019    2010s
4     5          1985    1980s
```